# Does Django password_reset support html email templates?

Tags: python, django

It seems to me django only supports plain text messages for password reset emails out of the box. How can I use html templates for this purpose?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

## Here is how you can do the override:

urls.py

```
url(r'^user/password/reset/$', 
    'YOUR_APP.views.password_reset', 
    {'post_reset_redirect' : '/#/login?resetemail=true'},
    name="password_reset"),
```

views.py

```
from django.contrib.auth.views import password_reset as django_password_reset
from YOUR_APP.forms import CustomPasswordResetForm

def password_reset(*args, **kwargs):
    """
        Overriding the Email Password Resert Forms Save to be able to send HTML email
    """
    kwargs['password_reset_form'] = CustomPasswordResetForm
    return django_password_reset(*args, **kwargs)
```

form.py

```
from django.contrib.auth.forms import PasswordResetForm
from django.contrib.auth.tokens import default_token_generator

class CustomPasswordResetForm(PasswordResetForm):
    """
        Overriding the Email Password Resert Forms Save to be able to send HTML email
    """
    def save(self, domain_override=None, email_template_name='registration/password_reset_email.html',
             use_https=False, token_generator=default_token_generator, request=None, email_subject_name='registration/password_reset_subject.txt', **kwargs):
        from django.core.mail import EmailMultiAlternatives
        from django.utils.html import strip_tags
        from django.template.loader import render_to_string
        from django.contrib.sites.models import get_current_site
        from django.utils.http import int_to_base36

        for user in self.users_cache:
            if not domain_override:
                current_site = get_current_site(request)
                site_name = current_site.name
                domain = current_site.domain
            else:
                 site_name = domain = domain_override

            c = {
                'email': user.email,
                'domain': domain,
                'site_name': site_name,
                'uid': int_to_base36(user.id),
                'user': user,
                'token': token_generator.make_token(user),
                'protocol': use_https and 'https' or 'http',
            }
            render = render_to_string(email_template_name, c)
            render_subject = render_to_string(email_subject_name, c)

            msg = EmailMultiAlternatives(render_subject, strip_tags(render), None, [user.email])
            msg.attach_alternative(render, "text/html")
            msg.send()
```

Comment: I get this error: AttributeError at /user/password/reset/
'CustomPasswordResetForm' object has no attribute 'users_cache'. 

Did you make a mistake? Should I use some other function instead of users_cache()? What do others do.

Answer (score 5):

You can override `save` method of `django.contrib.auth.forms.PasswordResetForm` and pass new form as an argument to `password_reset` view.

Answer (score 4):

## HTML Password Reset Email with Images in Django 3.0+

### Overview

1. Create three templates:

   - `password_reset_email.html`
   - `password_reset_email.txt`
   - `password_reset_subject.txt`
2. Override `django.contrib.auth.forms.PasswordResetForm` by creating a subclass.
3. Override the arguments for `PasswordResetForm.save()` to point to your custom templates.
4. Override `PasswordResetForm.send_email()` if you want to embed images in the HTML email.
5. Set `django.contrib.auth.views.PasswordResetView.form_class` to use your new `PasswordResetForm` subclass.

### 1. Create three templates

- In your Django templates directory, create a sub-directory named "registration".
- Under "templates/registration" add three templates:

  - `password_reset_email.html`
  - `password_reset_email.txt`
  - `password_reset_subject.txt`
- The HTML email template should be a well-structured HTML document. See example below.
- The "*.txt" template should just be a plain template (no HTML). See example below.

#### Example `password_reset_email.html`

```html
{% autoescape off %}
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1"/>

        <title>Password Reset</title>

        <style type="text/css">
            
            body {
                background-color: #ffffff;
                font-size: 14px;
                line-height: 16px;
                font-family: PTSansRegular,Arial,Helvetica,sans-serif;
                height: 100%;
                margin: 0;
                padding: 0;
                border: 0;
                outline: 0;
            }

            a.button {
                background-color: #007bff;
                border-color: #007bff;
                border-radius: 5px;
                color: #ffffff;
                cursor: pointer;
                display: inline-block;
                font-size: 15px;
                line-height: 18px;
                font-weight: bold;
                font-family: PTSansRegular,Arial,Helvetica,sans-serif;
                padding: 7px;
                text-align: center;
                text-decoration: none;
                white-space: nowrap;
                width: 150px;
            }

            .center {
                text-align: center
            }

            .container {
                min-height: 100%;
                min-width: 650px;
                position: relative;
                width: 100%;
            }

            p {
                text-align:left
            }

            table {
                margin: auto;
                width:650px;
            }

            td {
                padding-right: 14px;
                padding-left: 14px;
            }
        </style>
    </head>

    <body>

    <div class="container">

    <!-- BEGIN EMAIL -->
    <table align="center" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
    <tr>
        <td>
            <p>Hello {{ user.get_username }},</p>

            <p>A request has been received to change the password for your account.</p>

            <p class="center">
                <a target="_blank" class="button"
                        href="{{ protocol }}://{{ domain }}{% url 'password_reset_confirm' uidb64=uid token=token %}">
                    Reset Password
                </a>
            </p>

            <p>This link can only be used once. If you need to reset your password again, please visit
            <a href="{{ protocol }}://{{domain}}">{{ site_name }}</a> and request another reset.</p>

            <p>If you did not make this request, please contact us immediately at
            <a href="mailto: YOUR_SUPPORT_EMAIL">YOUR_SUPPORT_EMAIL</a>.</p>

            <p>Sincerely,</p>
            <p>The YOUR_COMPANY_NAME Team</p>
        </td>
    </tr>
    </table>
    <!-- END EMAIL -->

    <table class="spacer">
        <tr><td class="spacer">&nbsp;</td></tr>
    </table>

    <!-- BEGIN FOOTER -->
    <table align="center">
        <tr>
            <td>
                <p class="center"><img src="cid:logo" /></p>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td class="center">YOUR_ADDRESS_AND_OR_COPYRIGHT</td>
        </tr>
    </table>
    <!-- END FOOTER -->
    </div>

    </body>
</html>
{% endautoescape %}
```

#### Example `password_reset_email.txt`

```
{% autoescape off %}
Hello {{ user.get_username }},

A request has been received to change the password for your account. Click the link below to reset your password.

{{ protocol }}://{{ domain }}{% url 'password_reset_confirm' uidb64=uid token=token %}">

This link can only be used once. If you need to reset your password again, please visit
{{ protocol }}://{{domain}}">{{ site_name }} and request another reset.

If you did not make this request, please contact us immediately at YOUR_SUPPORT_EMAIL.

Sincerely,

The YOUR_COMPANY_NAME Team



YOUR_COMPANY_NAME
YOUR_ADDRESS_AND_OR_COPYRIGHT
{% endautoescape %}
```

### 2. Override `django.contrib.auth.forms.PasswordResetForm`

- In your Django app directory, create a module named "forms.py".
- Create a subclass of `django.contrib.auth.forms.PasswordResetForm` and override the `save()` method.

#### Example: forms.py

```py
class CustomPasswordResetForm(PasswordResetForm):
    """Override the default Django password-reset form to send the password reset 
    email using both HTML and plain text.
    """

    def save(
        self,
        domain_override: Optional[str] = None,
        subject_template_name: str = PASSWORD_RESET_SUBJECT_TEMPLATE,
        email_template_name: str = PASSWORD_RESET_TEXT_TEMPLATE,
        use_https: Optional[bool] = None,
        token_generator: PasswordResetTokenGenerator = default_token_generator,
        from_email: Optional[str] = FROM_EMAIL,
        request: Optional[WSGIRequest] = None,
        html_email_template_name: Optional[str] = PASSWORD_RESET_HTML_TEMPLATE,
        extra_email_context: Optional[Dict[str, str]] = None
    ) -> None:
        """Generate a one-use only link for resetting password and email it to 
        the user.

        Args:
            domain_override: Optional; Domain name to use in the email message 
                template that overrides the actual domain from which the email is 
                sent. Defaults to None.
            subject_template_name: Optional; Warning: this argument is overridden 
                by the global variable ``PASSWORD_RESET_SUBJECT_TEMPLATE``.
            email_template_name: Optional; Warning: this argument is overridden by 
                the global variable ``PASSWORD_RESET_TEXT_TEMPLATE``.
            use_https: Optional; If True, use HTTPS, otherwise use HTTP. Defaults 
                to False. Note that if the password reset HTTP request is received 
                via HTTPS, `use_https` will be set to True by the auth view.
            token_generator: Optional; Strategy object used to generate and check 
                tokens for the password reset mechanism. Defaults to an instance 
                of ``django.contrib.auth.tokens.PasswordResetTokenGenerator``.
            from_email: Optional; Warning: this argument is overridden by the 
                global variable``FROM_EMAIL``.
            request: Optional; The HttpRequest object. Defaults to None.
            html_email_template_name: Warning: this argument is overridden by the 
                global variable ``PASSWORD_RESET_HTML_TEMPLATE``.
            extra_email_context: Optional; Key-value pairs to add to the context 
                dictionary used to render the password reset email templates. 
                    Defaults to None.
        """
        email_template_name = PASSWORD_RESET_TEXT_TEMPLATE
        from_email = FROM_EMAIL
        html_email_template_name = PASSWORD_RESET_HTML_TEMPLATE
        subject_template_name = PASSWORD_RESET_SUBJECT_TEMPLATE

        email = self.cleaned_data["email"]
        if not domain_override:
            current_site = get_current_site(request)
            site_name = current_site.name
            domain = current_site.domain
        else:
            site_name = domain = domain_override
        UserModel = get_user_model()
        email_field_name = UserModel.get_email_field_name()  # type: ignore

        for user in self.get_users(email):
            user_email = getattr(user, email_field_name)
            context = {
                'email': user_email,
                'domain': domain,
                'site_name': site_name,
                'uid': urlsafe_base64_encode(force_bytes(user.pk)),
                'user': user,
                'token': token_generator.make_token(user),
                'protocol': 'https' if use_https else 'http',
                **(extra_email_context or {}),
            }

            self.send_mail(
                subject_template_name = subject_template_name,
                email_template_name = email_template_name,
                context = context,
                from_email = from_email,
                to_email = user_email,
                html_email_template_name = html_email_template_name
            )
```

### 3. Override the arguments for `PasswordResetForm.save()` to point to your custom templates.

- In your "forms.py" module, add global variables as follows:

#### Example forms.py

```py
from typing import Final


# Constants for sending password-reset emails.
LOGO_FILE_PATH: Final[str] = "img/logo.png"
LOGO_CID_NAME: Final[str] = "logo"
PASSWORD_RESET_FORM_TEMPLATE: Final[str] = "registration/password_reset_form.html"
PASSWORD_RESET_HTML_TEMPLATE: Final[str] = "registration/password_reset_email.html"
PASSWORD_RESET_TEXT_TEMPLATE: Final[str] = "registration/password_reset_email.txt"
PASSWORD_RESET_SUBJECT_TEMPLATE: Final[str] = "registration/password_reset_subject.txt"
SUPPORT_EMAIL: Final[str] = "YOUR_SUPPORT_EMAIL_ADDRESS"
FROM_EMAIL: Final[str] = f"YOUR_COMPANY_NAME Support <{SUPPORT_EMAIL}>"
```

### 4. Override `PasswordResetForm.send_email()` if you want to embed images in the HTML email.

#### Example: forms.py

```py
def get_as_mime_image(image_file_path: str, cid_name: str) -> MIMEImage:
    """Fetch an image file and return it wrapped in a ``MIMEImage`` object for use 
    in emails.

    After the ``MIMEImage`` has been attached to an email, reference the image in 
    the HTML using the Content ID.

    Example:

    If the CID name is "logo", then the HTML reference would be:

    <img src="cid:logo" />

    Args:
        image_file_path: The path of the image. The path must be findable by the 
            Django staticfiles app.
        cid_name: The Content-ID name to use within the HTML email body to 
            reference the image.

    Raises:
        FileNotFoundError: If the image file cannot be found by the staticfiles app.

    Returns:
        MIMEImage: The image wrapped in a ``MIMEImage`` object and the Content ID 
        set to ``cid_name``.
    """
    paths = finders.find(image_file_path)
    if paths is None:
        raise FileNotFoundError(f"{image_file_path} not found in static files")

    if isinstance(paths, list):
        final_path = paths[0]
    else:
        final_path = paths
    with open(final_path, 'rb') as f:
        image_data = f.read()

    mime_image = MIMEImage(image_data)
    mime_image.add_header("Content-ID", f"<{cid_name}>")
    return mime_image


class CustomPasswordResetForm(PasswordResetForm):
    """Override the default Django password-reset form to send the password reset email using both HTML and plain text.
    """
    def send_mail(
        self,
        subject_template_name: str,
        email_template_name: str,
        context: Dict[str, str],
        from_email: Optional[str],
        to_email: str,
        html_email_template_name: Optional[str] = None,
    ) -> None:
        """Send a ``django.core.mail.EmailMultiAlternatives`` to ``to_email``.

        This method also attaches the company logo, which can be added to the 
        email HTML template using:

        <img src="cid:logo" />

        Args:
            subject_template_name: Path of the template to use as the email 
                subject.
            email_template_name: Path of the template to use for the plain text 
                email body.
            context: A context dictionary to use when rendering the password reset 
                email templates.
            from_email: The From email address.
            to_email: The To email address.
            html_email_template_name: Optional; Path of the template to use for 
                the HTML email body. Defaults to None.
        """
        subject = loader.render_to_string(subject_template_name, context)
        # Email subject *must not* contain newlines
        subject = ''.join(subject.splitlines())
        body = loader.render_to_string(email_template_name, context)

        email_message = EmailMultiAlternatives(subject, body, 
                                               from_email=from_email, to=[to_email],
                                               reply_to=[from_email])
        if html_email_template_name is not None:
            html_email = loader.render_to_string(html_email_template_name, context)
            email_message.attach_alternative(html_email, 'text/html')
            email_message.mixed_subtype = "related"
            mime_image = get_as_mime_image(image_file_path=LOGO_FILE_PATH, cid_name=LOGO_CID_NAME)
            email_message.attach(mime_image)  # type: ignore

        email_message.send()
```

### 5. Set `django.contrib.auth.views.PasswordResetView.form_class` to use your new `PasswordResetForm` subclass.

#### Django urls.py file

```py
from django.contrib.auth import views

from your_app.forms import CustomPasswordResetForm


views.PasswordResetView.form_class = CustomPasswordResetForm

urlpatterns = [
    path('', home_view, name='home'),
    path('accounts/', include('django.contrib.auth.urls')),
    ...
]
```

## Complete forms.py

```py
"""Module that overrides the default Django password reset functionality by 
sending emails containing both plain text as well as HTML along with the company logo.
"""

from email.mime.image import MIMEImage
from typing import Dict, Final, Optional

from django.contrib.auth import get_user_model
from django.contrib.auth.forms import PasswordResetForm
from django.contrib.auth.tokens import default_token_generator, PasswordResetTokenGenerator
from django.contrib.sites.shortcuts import get_current_site
from django.contrib.staticfiles import finders
from django.core.handlers.wsgi import WSGIRequest
from django.core.mail import EmailMultiAlternatives
from django.template import loader
from django.utils.encoding import force_bytes
from django.utils.http import urlsafe_base64_encode


# Constants for sending password-reset emails.
LOGO_FILE_PATH: Final[str] = "img/logo.png"
LOGO_CID_NAME: Final[str] = "logo"
PASSWORD_RESET_FORM_TEMPLATE: Final[str] = "registration/password_reset_form.html"
PASSWORD_RESET_HTML_TEMPLATE: Final[str] = "registration/password_reset_email.html"
PASSWORD_RESET_TEXT_TEMPLATE: Final[str] = "registration/password_reset_email.txt"
PASSWORD_RESET_SUBJECT_TEMPLATE: Final[str] = "registration/password_reset_subject.txt"
SUPPORT_EMAIL: Final[str] = "YOUR_SUPPORT_EMAIL_ADDRESS"
FROM_EMAIL: Final[str] = f"YOUR_COMPANY_NAME Support <{SUPPORT_EMAIL}>"


def get_as_mime_image(image_file_path: str, cid_name: str) -> MIMEImage:
    """Fetch an image file and return it wrapped in a ``MIMEImage`` object for use 
    in emails.

    After the ``MIMEImage`` has been attached to an email, reference the image in 
    the HTML using the Content ID.

    Example:

    If the CID name is "logo", then the HTML reference would be:

    <img src="cid:logo" />

    Args:
        image_file_path: The path of the image. The path must be findable by the 
            Django staticfiles app.
        cid_name: The Content-ID name to use within the HTML email body to 
            reference the image.

    Raises:
        FileNotFoundError: If the image file cannot be found by the staticfiles app.

    Returns:
        MIMEImage: The image wrapped in a ``MIMEImage`` object and the Content ID 
        set to ``cid_name``.
    """
    paths = finders.find(image_file_path)
    if paths is None:
        raise FileNotFoundError(f"{image_file_path} not found in static files")

    if isinstance(paths, list):
        final_path = paths[0]
    else:
        final_path = paths
    with open(final_path, 'rb') as f:
        image_data = f.read()

    mime_image = MIMEImage(image_data)
    mime_image.add_header("Content-ID", f"<{cid_name}>")
    return mime_image


class CustomPasswordResetForm(PasswordResetForm):
    """Override the default Django password-reset form to send the password reset email using both HTML and plain text.
    """
    def send_mail(
        self,
        subject_template_name: str,
        email_template_name: str,
        context: Dict[str, str],
        from_email: Optional[str],
        to_email: str,
        html_email_template_name: Optional[str] = None,
    ) -> None:
        """Send a ``django.core.mail.EmailMultiAlternatives`` to ``to_email``.

        This method also attaches the company logo, which can be added to the 
        email HTML template using:

        <img src="cid:logo" />

        Args:
            subject_template_name: Path of the template to use as the email 
                subject.
            email_template_name: Path of the template to use for the plain text 
                email body.
            context: A context dictionary to use when rendering the password reset 
                email templates.
            from_email: The From email address.
            to_email: The To email address.
            html_email_template_name: Optional; Path of the template to use for 
                the HTML email body. Defaults to None.
        """
        subject = loader.render_to_string(subject_template_name, context)
        # Email subject *must not* contain newlines
        subject = ''.join(subject.splitlines())
        body = loader.render_to_string(email_template_name, context)

        email_message = EmailMultiAlternatives(subject, body, 
                                               from_email=from_email, to=[to_email],
                                               reply_to=[from_email])
        if html_email_template_name is not None:
            html_email = loader.render_to_string(html_email_template_name, context)
            email_message.attach_alternative(html_email, 'text/html')
            email_message.mixed_subtype = "related"
            mime_image = get_as_mime_image(image_file_path=LOGO_FILE_PATH, cid_name=LOGO_CID_NAME)
            email_message.attach(mime_image)  # type: ignore

        email_message.send()

    def save(
        self,
        domain_override: Optional[str] = None,
        subject_template_name: str = PASSWORD_RESET_SUBJECT_TEMPLATE,
        email_template_name: str = PASSWORD_RESET_TEXT_TEMPLATE,
        use_https: Optional[bool] = None,
        token_generator: PasswordResetTokenGenerator = default_token_generator,
        from_email: Optional[str] = FROM_EMAIL,
        request: Optional[WSGIRequest] = None,
        html_email_template_name: Optional[str] = PASSWORD_RESET_HTML_TEMPLATE,
        extra_email_context: Optional[Dict[str, str]] = None
    ) -> None:
        """Generate a one-use only link for resetting password and email it to 
        the user.

        Args:
            domain_override: Optional; Domain name to use in the email message 
                template that overrides the actual domain from which the email is 
                sent. Defaults to None.
            subject_template_name: Optional; Warning: this argument is overridden 
                by the global variable ``PASSWORD_RESET_SUBJECT_TEMPLATE``.
            email_template_name: Optional; Warning: this argument is overridden by 
                the global variable ``PASSWORD_RESET_TEXT_TEMPLATE``.
            use_https: Optional; If True, use HTTPS, otherwise use HTTP. Defaults 
                to False. Note that if the password reset HTTP request is received 
                via HTTPS, `use_https` will be set to True by the auth view.
            token_generator: Optional; Strategy object used to generate and check 
                tokens for the password reset mechanism. Defaults to an instance 
                of ``django.contrib.auth.tokens.PasswordResetTokenGenerator``.
            from_email: Optional; Warning: this argument is overridden by the 
                global variable``FROM_EMAIL``.
            request: Optional; The HttpRequest object. Defaults to None.
            html_email_template_name: Warning: this argument is overridden by the 
                global variable ``PASSWORD_RESET_HTML_TEMPLATE``.
            extra_email_context: Optional; Key-value pairs to add to the context 
                dictionary used to render the password reset email templates. 
                    Defaults to None.
        """
        email_template_name = PASSWORD_RESET_TEXT_TEMPLATE
        from_email = FROM_EMAIL
        html_email_template_name = PASSWORD_RESET_HTML_TEMPLATE
        subject_template_name = PASSWORD_RESET_SUBJECT_TEMPLATE

        email = self.cleaned_data["email"]
        if not domain_override:
            current_site = get_current_site(request)
            site_name = current_site.name
            domain = current_site.domain
        else:
            site_name = domain = domain_override
        UserModel = get_user_model()
        email_field_name = UserModel.get_email_field_name()  # type: ignore

        for user in self.get_users(email):
            user_email = getattr(user, email_field_name)
            context = {
                'email': user_email,
                'domain': domain,
                'site_name': site_name,
                'uid': urlsafe_base64_encode(force_bytes(user.pk)),
                'user': user,
                'token': token_generator.make_token(user),
                'protocol': 'https' if use_https else 'http',
                **(extra_email_context or {}),
            }

            self.send_mail(
                subject_template_name = subject_template_name,
                email_template_name = email_template_name,
                context = context,
                from_email = from_email,
                to_email = user_email,
                html_email_template_name = html_email_template_name
            )
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use PasswordResetSerializer
http://django-rest-auth.readthedocs.io/en/latest/configuration.html

Then you can override all the form options:

domain_override
subject_template_name
email_template_name
use_https
token_generator
from_email
request
html_email_template_name
extra_email_context

in my case i just override 2 props

```
class CustomPasswordResetSerializer(PasswordResetSerializer):

    def get_email_options(self):
        return {
            'domain_override': 'anydomain.com',
            'html_email_template_name': 'your_temp/password_reset_email.html',
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is the simple approach worked for me. Add our custom template path in such a way worked for me.

`path('users/password/reset/', password_reset, {'html_email_template_name': 'registration/password_reset_email.html'},name='password_reset'),`

Answer (score 0):

After some amount of trial and error, I discovered a much, much more terse way to supply a custom templated password reset email in the latest version of Django (1.8).

In your `project/urls.py`, add these imports:

```
from django.contrib.auth import views as auth_views
from django.core.urlresolvers import reverse_lazy
```

And add the following route in your urlpatterns before the usual django contrib auth url route inclusion:

```
url(r'^accounts/password/reset/$',
  auth_views.password_reset,
  {
    'post_reset_redirect': reverse_lazy('auth_password_reset_done'),
    'html_email_template_name': 'registration/password_reset_html_email.html'
  },
  name='auth_password_reset'),


url('^', include('django.contrib.auth.urls')),
```

And then, in your app's `templates/registration` folder, create the `password_reset_html_email.html` with whatever HTML template you want.

The reason this seemed necessary lay in the source for `django/contrib/auth/views.py`, which has the view function the original URL route is mapped to:

```
147 def password_reset(request, is_admin_site=False,
148                    template_name='registration/password_reset_form.html',
149                    email_template_name='registration/password_reset_email.html',
150                    subject_template_name='registration/password_reset_subject.txt',
151                    password_reset_form=PasswordResetForm,
152                    token_generator=default_token_generator,
153                    post_reset_redirect=None,
154                    from_email=None,
155                    current_app=None,
156                    extra_context=None,
157                    html_email_template_name=None):
158
```

The `html_email_template_name` is set to `None` as default, and there didn't seem to be a way to assign its value, aside from rewriting this specific route for this case as I mentioned above.

Hopefully this helps without needing to copy-paste a bunch of nearly-identical code like some of the other answers suggested - feedback is welcome, of course!

Answer (score 0):

For me the research was time consuming but the solution rather trivial. **No overrides no fiddling with forms or anything like that**
am using Django==1.8.6 but should work from at least django 1.7 onward. To enable support for html formatted emails in password_reset all I had to do is change the email template key name in reset function from email_template_name='emails/password_reset_email_html.html

to

**html**_email_template_name='emails/password_reset_email_html.html',

thus the reset function would look as such:

```
def reset(request):
# Wrap the built-in password reset view and pass it the arguments
# like the template name, email template name, subject template name
# and the url to redirect after the password reset is initiated.
return password_reset(request, template_name='profile/reset.html',
    html_email_template_name='emails/password_reset_email_html.html',
    subject_template_name='emails/reset_subject.txt',
    post_reset_redirect=reverse('success'))
```

Comment: Where is the proper place in the django project structure to put this?

Answer (score 0):

Based on Cem Kozinoglu solution I would suggest to change the form and  overload send_mail instead of save method in the following way:

```
class CustomPasswordResetForm(PasswordResetForm):

    def send_mail(self, subject_template_name, email_template_name,
                  context, from_email, to_email, html_email_template_name=None):
        """
            Sends a django.core.mail.EmailMultiAlternatives to `to_email`.
        """
        subject = loader.render_to_string(subject_template_name, context)
        # Email subject *must not* contain newlines
        subject = ''.join(subject.splitlines())
        body = loader.render_to_string(email_template_name, context)

        email_message = EmailMultiAlternatives(subject, body, from_email, [to_email])
        # New line introduce
        email_message.attach_alternative(body, 'text/html')

        if html_email_template_name is not None:
            html_email = loader.render_to_string(html_email_template_name, context)
            email_message.attach_alternative(html_email, 'text/html')

        email_message.send()
```

Answer (score 0):

After overwriting the **PasswordResetForm** and adding this line of code after email_message initialization I solve my problem:

```
email_message.attach_alternative(body, 'text/html')
```