# How to make Django Password Reset Email Beautiful HTML?

Tags: django

My Django application currently is setup to use the native registration package to handle user  authentication and management.

I have created a handful of files in `myApp/templates/registration` that are used to send out the password reset token as described in [these docs](http://garmoncheg.blogspot.com/2012/07/django-resetting-passwords-with.html).

It works fine. Except the password reset email is an ugly text-only monstrosity. I would like to make it match the look and feel of all other emails my application sends. IE: I want it to be HTML and contain images, styles and links. How do I do that?

I followed the detailed instructions [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18990041/1742777). However, there is an error in that code that I don't know what to do with: `'CustomPasswordResetForm' object has no attribute 'users_cache'`

Can someone show me a detailed working example how to accomplish this? I wish it weren't so hard.

Answer (score 16):

Adding my findings for django version 2.0 as I found the rest of the answers to this question to be out-of-date.

With 2.0, the proper way of adding a URL to your urls.py file is by using `path()`:

```
from django.urls import path
from django.contrib.auth import views as auth_views

path('accounts/password_reset/', auth_views.PasswordResetView.as_view(
  html_email_template_name='registration/password_reset_html_email.html'
)),
```

The next code snippet to highlight here is the `.as_view()` function. Django 2.0 implements auth views as classes. You can read more about this in the [Authentication Views documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/auth/default/#module-django.contrib.auth.views)

You then "convert" the class to a view using `.as_view() and you are able to pass in any class attributes defined in the source code as named parameters.

Passing in html_email_template_name (which defaults to None) automatically sends an html email.

You can access the source code for PasswordResetView by following this python path: django.contrib.auth.views

Here you can see the other class attributes you can pass into PasswordResetView and the other auth views. This is super helpful for passing extra_context into your django templates as well.

Answer (score 11):

[cross-posted from [Does Django password_reset support html email templates?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7965611/does-django-password-reset-support-html-email-templates/30886960#30886960) ]

After some amount of trial and error, I discovered a much, much more terse way to supply a custom templated password reset email in the latest version of Django (1.8).

In your `project/urls.py`, add these imports:

```
from django.contrib.auth import views as auth_views
from django.core.urlresolvers import reverse_lazy
```

And add the following route in your urlpatterns before the usual django contrib auth url route inclusion:

```
url(r'^accounts/password/reset/$',
  auth_views.password_reset,
  {
    'post_reset_redirect': reverse_lazy('auth_password_reset_done'),
    'html_email_template_name': 'registration/password_reset_html_email.html'
  },
  name='auth_password_reset'),


url('^', include('django.contrib.auth.urls')),
```

And then, in your app's `templates/registration` folder, create the `password_reset_html_email.html` with whatever HTML template you want.

The reason this seemed necessary lay in the source for `django/contrib/auth/views.py`, which has the view function the original URL route is mapped to:

```
147 def password_reset(request, is_admin_site=False,
148                    template_name='registration/password_reset_form.html',
149                    email_template_name='registration/password_reset_email.html',
150                    subject_template_name='registration/password_reset_subject.txt',
151                    password_reset_form=PasswordResetForm,
152                    token_generator=default_token_generator,
153                    post_reset_redirect=None,
154                    from_email=None,
155                    current_app=None,
156                    extra_context=None,
157                    html_email_template_name=None):
158
```

The `html_email_template_name` is set to `None` as default, and there didn't seem to be a way to assign its value, aside from rewriting this specific route for this case as I mentioned above.

Hopefully this helps without needing to copy-paste a bunch of nearly-identical code like some of the other answers suggested - feedback is welcome, of course!

Comment: this worked for me on Django 1.11. The url function admits kwargs. This is the documentation: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/urls/#url

Answer (score 10):

The default helper views for django authentication cannot send multi-part (HTML) emails because the underlying [`send_mail`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/topics/email/) method does not support HTML emails *yet*.

*This will be fixed in the next release, by adding a `html_message` flag.*

The easiest way to fix this is to create your own custom password reset form, and use [`EmailMultiAlternatives`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/topics/email/#sending-alternative-content-types) to send your message, thus allowing your HTML to render correctly in the email client.

You can use the [existing form](https://github.com/django/django/blob/stable/1.6.x/django/contrib/auth/forms.py#L216), and make your changes:

```
class HTMLPasswordResetForm(forms.Form):
    email = forms.EmailField(label=_("Email"), max_length=254)

    def save(self, domain_override=None,
             subject_template_name='registration/password_reset_subject.txt',
             email_template_name='registration/password_reset_email.html',
             use_https=False, token_generator=default_token_generator,
             from_email=None, request=None):
        """
        Generates a one-use only link for resetting password and sends to the
        user.
        """
        # from django.core.mail import send_mail
        from django.core.mail import EmailMultiAlternatives
        UserModel = get_user_model()
        email = self.cleaned_data["email"]
        active_users = UserModel._default_manager.filter(
            email__iexact=email, is_active=True)
        for user in active_users:
            # Make sure that no email is sent to a user that actually has
            # a password marked as unusable
            if not user.has_usable_password():
                continue
            if not domain_override:
                current_site = get_current_site(request)
                site_name = current_site.name
                domain = current_site.domain
            else:
                site_name = domain = domain_override
            c = {
                'email': user.email,
                'domain': domain,
                'site_name': site_name,
                'uid': urlsafe_base64_encode(force_bytes(user.pk)),
                'user': user,
                'token': token_generator.make_token(user),
                'protocol': 'https' if use_https else 'http',
            }
            subject = loader.render_to_string(subject_template_name, c)
            # Email subject *must not* contain newlines
            subject = ''.join(subject.splitlines())
            email = loader.render_to_string(email_template_name, c)

            msg = EmailMessage(subject, email, from_email, [user.email])
            msg.content_subtype = "html"  # Main content is now text/html
            msg.send()

            #send_mail(subject, email, from_email, [user.email])
```

Once you have done that, change your [`password_reset`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/topics/auth/default/#django.contrib.auth.views.password_reset) method call and pass in your new form class:

```
password_reset(request, password_reset_form=HTMLPasswordResetForm)
```

Comment: Burhan, How do I change my existing password_reset call? I don't see this being called anywhere. Please point me the file name. I have added your form above in my forms.py. But I'm still unsure what should go in my views.py and in urls.py (BTW, there are 2 urls.py as you know. I have made my change in the one for my app -- not the global one)

Comment: Create your own custom view to reset passwords.

Answer (score 7):

**Django 2**

You can create a custom template in the `templates` folder: `templates/registration/password_reset_email.html` and add it to your main `urls.py`.

```
# add this import
from django.contrib.auth import views as auth_views

...


# add this path
path('accounts/password_reset/', auth_views.PasswordResetView.as_view(
    html_email_template_name='registration/password_reset_email.html'
)),
# just before this line (to take priority over the default one)
path('accounts/', include('django.contrib.auth.urls')),
```

Comment: The comments in the code are confusing. Would you correct it? `# just before` should be replaced with `# just after`. OR it is better if you just cut and paste the **last line** to the above of `path('accounts/password_reset/', ...)`

Answer (score 3):

For django2.2 use this thing to add a custom email template in the password reset email template

In urls.py file add these lines

```
urlpatterns = [
path('password-reset', 
            auth_views.PasswordResetView.as_view(
            template_name='accounts/password_reset.html', 
            html_email_template_name="accounts/email_reset_template.html",
            email_template_name='accounts/password_reset_email.html', 
            subject_template_name="accounts/password_reset_subject.txt",
            ),
             name="password_reset"),

    path('password-reset/done', 
        auth_views.PasswordResetDoneView.as_view(
            template_name='accounts/password_reset_done.html'),
             name="password_reset_done"),

    path('password-reset-complete/', 
        auth_views.PasswordResetCompleteView.as_view(
            template_name='accounts/password_reset_complete.html'),
             name="password_reset_complete"),

    path('password-reset-confirm/<uidb64>/<token>/', 
        auth_views.PasswordResetConfirmView.as_view(
            template_name='accounts/password_reset_confirm.html'),
             name="password_reset_confirm"),

#Add more urls you want
]
```

After adding above lines you can omit the email_template name from 'password_reset' if you provide the html template name but to use template in the email sent via email you need the html template now choose your own html template 
from different webiste you want and place that file inside the same folders where all password reset files are there.

Now important part is to add the link inside your custom html template to add this you need to add the following lines to your custom html template like this:

```
<a  href="{{ protocol }}://{{ domain }}{% url 'password_reset_confirm' uidb64=uid token=token %}" style=".."> Reset Password </a>
```

and you can add the below line anywhere in the html template according to your needs

```
     {% load i18n %}
{% autoescape off %}  You're receiving this e-mail because you requested a password reset for your Xandar account. {% trans "Thanks for using our site!" %} {% blocktrans %}The {{ site_name }} team{% endblocktrans %} {% endautoescape %}
```

If you still having any doubt then let me know

This definitely works and I have used this in my project.

Comment: i am not able to get it work. my question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65335440/django-auth-password-reset-not-working-on-localhost

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried to edit this template?
registration/password_reset_email.html

You can add a password_reset_email.html file to your templates/registration folder in your project, then add the relevant sections / HTML to get a nice template.
The default template is empty.

Comment: Yes. I tried that. But when you put HTML in this file, the HTML code shows up in the body of the email.

Comment: See Burhan Halid's answer below - you need to override the function in order to support multipart/html sending

Answer (score 1):

I solved this by changing the parameter of password_reset function in django.contrib.auth views file. By default html_email_template_name is None. 
If you direct it to 'registration/password_reset_email.html' file, its sending emails with proper html.

```
def password_reset(request,
               template_name='registration/password_reset_form.html',
               email_template_name='registration/password_reset_email.html',
               subject_template_name='registration/password_reset_subject.txt',
               password_reset_form=PasswordResetForm,
               token_generator=default_token_generator,
               post_reset_redirect=None,
               from_email=None,
               extra_context=None,
              html_email_template_name='registration/password_reset_email.html',
               extra_email_context=None):
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to overide the default html. To do that goto you django istallation folder in `libs/site-packages/django` and copy `password_reset_email.html` from django templates and paste it in `[templates]/registration/password_reset_email.html`. Then define your CSS and edit the the default html and if your HTML code shows up in body turn off django template manager auto escaping but it's not recommanded.

Comment: The template is in django/contrib/admin/templates/registration/...  I think answers must be more explanatory..

Answer (score 0):

You can do the following.

Add both to the password_reset:

```
html_email_template_name='YOUR TEMPLATE PATH',
email_template_name='YOUR TEMPLATE PATH'
```

It worked for me (Django 1.11)

Answer (score 0):

The simplest (and honestly only way) to force the email to be sent as HTML was to override the `form_valid` method.

views.py:

```
class MyPasswordResetView(PasswordResetView):

  # forcing to use HTML email template (param: html_email_template_name)
  def form_valid(self, form):
      opts = {
          'use_https': self.request.is_secure(),
          'token_generator': self.token_generator,
          'from_email': self.from_email,
          'email_template_name': self.email_template_name,
          'subject_template_name': self.subject_template_name,
          'request': self.request,
          'html_email_template_name': 'registration/password_reset_email.html',
          'extra_email_context': self.extra_email_context,
      }
      form.save(**opts)
      return HttpResponseRedirect(self.get_success_url())
```

urls.py

```
path('password_reset/', myapp.MyPasswordResetView.as_view(), name='password_reset'),
```

Answer (score 0):

1) Add a password_reset_email.html file to your templates/registration folder in your project "myApp". 
2) Move 'django.contrib.admin' below 'myApp' in your INSTALLED_APPS.
https://github.com/macropin/django-registration/issues/50#issuecomment-142637807

Not the best solution, but it worked for me!