# Django authentication process, how to render the template of email?

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms, django-views

I'm setting the authentication process in my Django project.

In my `password_reset_email.html` I have set the following code:

```
Someone requested a password reset for the account associated with the email {{email}}.
If you haven't changed any passwords, I will ignore this email.
Follow the link in case you proceed:
    
    {{protocol}}://{{domain}}{% url 'password_reset_confirm' uidb64=uid token=token %}
```

But when I send the e-mail, the hyperlink does not work; there appears only the text of the link.

How could get a working hyperlink?

Comment: By default, django.contrib.auth.PasswordReset View only sends a TXT email, which means a plain text email.

If you want to send html formatted emails you should use `html_email_template_name` attribute

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The relevant docs for you would be [`PasswordResetView.html_email_template_name`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/auth/default/#django.contrib.auth.views.PasswordResetView):

> `html_email_template_name`: The full name of a template to use for generating a `text/html` multipart email with the password reset link. By default, HTML email is not sent.

With this, your code could look something like this:

```
path(
    'accounts/password_reset/',
    PasswordResetView.as_view(
        html_email_template_name='my_email_template.html')),
```

See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49212347/9225671) of a very similar question.