# How to change the template of password-reset-email properly Django

Tags: python, html, django, email, templates

This line of code is responsible from sending an email which contains a password reset link.

`path('accounts/password-reset/', auth_views.PasswordResetView.as_view(), name='password_reset'),`

However the email looks completely dull and it is difficult to distinguish important parts while reading.

To attract the attention of the user and direct them better I would like to add style to this body of email.

It is possible to add custom template to the email by these lines:

```
...
path('accounts/', include('django.contrib.auth.urls')),
path('accounts/password-reset/', auth_views.PasswordResetView.as_view(html_email_template_name='registration/password_reset_email.html'), name='password_reset'),
...
```

The thing is the reset-link inside the email consists of a uidb64 value and a token, such as:

```
localhost:8000/password-reset/calculated_uidb64/calculated_token
```

What is the proper way to pass these values to the custom template of `password_reset_email.html`?

Comment: Have a look at this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21793829/how-to-make-django-password-reset-email-beautiful-html

Comment: @HemantMalik Thanks a lot. I actually have a comment on the topic you shared. The problem is I couldn't figure out how to pass the necessary parameters into the template. Does django calculate the whole link and I somehow pass that link to the template? Or should I form the link from scratch using uidb64 and the token? If so how?

Comment: I just found your comment. Have you tried this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/56530555/10140011

Comment: @HemantMalik I don't understand the funtion of .txt files. Also I dont know how to style and position the reset-link inside the email template. How to pass the link parameter?

Comment: In the shared answer above, it is suggested to add `<a  href="{{ protocol }}://{{ domain }}{% url 'password_reset_confirm' uidb64=uid token=token %}" style=".."> Reset Password </a>
` in template to add url, have you tried this. Also, I found an article which justifies the answer shared above. Have a look at http://garmoncheg.blogspot.com/2012/07/django-resetting-passwords-with.html

Comment: @HemantMalik That worked man. Thanks a lot. I was on the page you linked but missed the critical information. Actually I was thinking the django version would be too old and did not bother to read in detail, as django has the probability to have dramatic changes between versions. Provided that you have time I would be glad if you would reorder your comments as an actual answer so that the solution would be obvious for everyone, especially for those using the newer version of django.

Comment: I have added an answer based on my understanding, just as you suggested. Feel free to suggest any changes if i missed something. Cheers!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Here are few things that you need to know before using custom email template in django PasswordResetView.

1. django uses `registration/password_reset_email.html` as default file for email content for password reset unless you defined/provided it explicitly in `PasswordResetView`'s `html_email_template_name` param value.
2. Django allows jinja templating inside the email template to modify it based on your requirement.
3. PasswordResetView provides ready to use context needed for password reset view out of the box. Such as user instance to fill in any user details, site_name, token, etc.

Here is a sample of the email template using context via django templating.

```
{% autoescape off %}
You're receiving this e-mail because you requested a password reset for your user account at {{ site_name }}.

Please go to the following page and choose a new password:
{% block reset_link %}
{{ protocol }}://{{ domain }}{% url django.contrib.auth.views.password_reset_confirm uidb36=uid, token=token %}
{% endblock %}

Your username, in case you've forgotten: {{ user.username }}

Thanks for using our site!

The {{ site_name }} team.

{% endautoescape %}
```

Context used(or can be used) in above template are as follows:

```
email: An alias for user.email
user: The current User, according to the email form field. Only active users are able to reset their passwords (User.is_active is True).
site_name: An alias for site.name. If you don’t have the site framework installed, this will be set to the value of request.META['SERVER_NAME']. For more on sites, see The “sites” framework.
domain: An alias for site.domain. If you don’t have the site framework installed, this will be set to the value of request.get_host().
protocol: http or https
uid: The user’s primary key encoded in base 64.
token: Token to check that the reset link is valid.
```

Note: As user is a user model instance, other values such as user.id, user.contact_number can also be used in email template.

**Useful resources:**

1. I would highly recommend this [article](http://garmoncheg.blogspot.com/2012/07/django-resetting-passwords-with.html) addressing [Django: Resetting Passwords (with internal tools)](http://garmoncheg.blogspot.com/2012/07/django-resetting-passwords-with.html)
2. [Official django documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/auth/default/#django.contrib.auth.views.PasswordResetView) describing useful options and context.
3. [Code in django repository](https://github.com/django/django/blob/d01709aae21de9cd2565b9c52f32732ea28a2d98/django/contrib/auth/views.py#L212) for in-depth understanding of how `PasswordResetVieww` works.

Comment: Wow, I was also looking for the context tags. The answer provides more than I asked for. Good to meet people who can understand the other side and provide without asking. Thanks a lot. Wish you the best.